# Avoid duplicates in a union in prolog

Tags: prolog

Data:

```
%flight(FID, Start, Destination, Company, Seats).
%-------------------------------------------------
flight(1, 'China', 'Germany', 'Lufthansa', 210).
flight(2, 'Germany', 'Dubai', 'Lufthansa', 400).
flight(3, 'China', 'Germany', 'Lufthansa', 350).
flight(4, 'Japan', 'China', 'Eurowings', 50).
flight(5, 'Russia', 'China', 'Condor', 150).
flight(6, 'China', 'China', 'Condor', 2).
```

I want to get the flights that start or land in china. First I came up with

```
q2(FID) :- flight(FID, 'China', _, _, _).
q2(FID) :- flight(FID, _, 'China', _, _).
```

This creates a union of flights that start or land in china. However this gives me duplicates:

```
F = 1 ;
F = 3 ;
F = 6 ;
F = 4 ;
F = 5 ;
F = 6.
```

How can I have F = 6 only once in the list? I can only use a limited set of operators: , . ! < > = +

Comment: I think we had this already. The solution to this is again, to use the IDs.

Comment: @Boris yeah I tried but it was not working the same way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your predicate for `q2/1` is defined, fact id 6 satisfies it twice (once for each clause). You could fix it by applying more exclusive conditions in your clauses:

```
q2(FID) :- flight(FID, 'China', D, _, _), D \== 'China'.
q2(FID) :- flight(FID, S, 'China', _, _), S \== 'China'.
q2(FID) :- flight(FID, 'China', 'China', _, _).
```

Now the clauses find all the desired facts, but are mutually exclusive.

Alternatively, you could use `setof/3` to collect them:

```
setof(F, q2(F), Fs).
```